# Non-separated quotient of separated scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, invariant-theory, geometric-invariant-theory

I am reading Mumford's GIT book. I found the following claim there.

Let $X$ be an algebraic variety. Let $G$ be an algebraic group acting on $X$. Then the categorical quotient of $X$ by $G$ may be non-separated.

**Question**:  Could you construct an example?

Comment: What about $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ acting on $\mathbb{A}^2$ by multplication by $-1$?

Comment: The factor is quadratic cone. I.e. It is closed subvariety of $\mathbb{A}^3$ defined by equation $xz=y^2$.It is a singular variety, but it is separated.

Comment: Thanks! Hmm, interesting. Is that true? I believe, you now. I guess we want to do the OPPOSITE. Instead of trying to pinch two points together, we want to pinch everything but a point. Yeah/

Comment: @Alex Youcis There is a theorem, which states that categorical quotient of an affine scheme by a reductive group is an affine scheme (just the spectrum of invariants, by the way). In particular, such quotient is separated.

Comment: Ah, of course! How could I have forgotten this. Yeah, I'm out of ideas—sorry. I would think about taking solvable groups like $B_n$ and looking at quotients, but the obvious ones (e.g. $\text{GL}_n/B_n$ :P) are quasi-projective.

Comment: The quotient of $\mathbf{C}^2 \setminus \{0\}$ by the $\mathbf{C}^*$-action $\lambda(a,b) = (\lambda a,\lambda^{-1}b)$ is a simple example: $\mathbf{C}^2 \setminus \{0\}//\mathbf{C}^*$ ends up being the line with two origins. You can compute it explicitly by computing rings of invariants on affine charts; see Cox–Little–Schenck's [Toric Varieties](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2810322), Ex. 5.0.15.

Answer (score 4):

This answer is given by Takumi Murayama. I am just writing down the details.

Consider the quotient of $X = \mathbb{C}^2 \backslash \{ 0 \}$ by $\mathbb{C}^*$ action $\lambda (x, y) = ( \lambda x, \lambda^{-1} y )$.

We can consider two charts

$U_1 = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{C}^2 \backslash \{ 0 \}$   such that  $x \neq 0 \}$

$U_2 = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{C}^2 \backslash \{ 0 \}$   such that  $y \neq 0 \}$

Let me consider $z= xy$ and $t=x$ as coordinates on $U_1$. 
 $U_1 = \mathbb{C} \times \Big( \mathbb{C}  \backslash \{ 0 \} \Big) $ where $z \in \mathbb{C}$ and $t \in \mathbb{C} \backslash \{ 0 \}$. The action is given by $\lambda(z, t ) = (z, \lambda t)$. So the quotient $U_1 / G$ is $\mathbb{C}$ with coordinate $z = xy$.

If one swap $x$ and $y$, the same words could be repeated for $U_2$. So the quotient $U_2 / G$ is also $\mathbb{C}$ with coordinate $xy$. Quotient of $( U_1 \cap U_2 ) / G$ is $\mathbb{C} \backslash \{ 0 \}$.

Quotient of whole thing $(U_1 \cup U_2)/G$ cab be obtained by gluing $U_1 / G$ and $U_2 / G$ along $(U_1 \cap U_2)/G$. So we get a line two origins indeed.